# Need to click twice to get IE to update selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a selectbox;

```
<select id="dynbox">
<option value="">Please enter field1 first</option>
</select>
```

Now when input field1 has got content, the ajax call gets some JSON data back in return to fill with the options.

```
$('#dynbox option').remove();
$.each(data.results, function(cell, value) {
    $('<option/>').val(value.id).text(value.naam).appendTo('#dynbox');
});
```

All works fine with Chrome etc, but IE I do see the option been removed, a blank option shown first, but as soon as I click on the select box, I get dropdown with the original, removed option. And if I click again, I get the correct list.

What can I do to stop users needing to click twice to get the list to be updated in IE?

Comment: Well, we all know that IE can be difficult at times. Have you tried to build a html string of options and set the html of dynbox? i.e. before the `each` declare `var optios_html = '';`, append to the string in the each loop and then after the loop `$('#dynbox').html(optios_html);`. I know this isn't as clean jquery, but it is worth the try. btw. that way you don't need the remove

Comment: @skarist I had that as my first set of code; but without any luck.

Comment: Ok, have you tried to force repaint of the box, i.e. `var dynbox = $('#dynbox');
dynbox.css("display", "none");
var redraw = dynbox.offsetHeight;
dynbox.css("display", "block");`?

Comment: @skarist no luck; on my laptop I don't have the same problem. But many others do.

Comment: I fixed it by resetting the height in the time it was hidden.

Comment: can you rule out this is not a styling issue? maybe you need some ``display:block`` on your click target

Comment: I found that IE dev tools has the same issue on default when selecting a user agent to simulate.